# Custom Logo URL | Help me print the URL of the custom logo I inserted into my theme

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, logo

I am trying to use the separate components of the_custom_logo() function to create my own display for the logo.

**Please can someone inform me as to how I can access the url and the image reference separate to each other?**

A lot of people have asked how to change the URL which is not the question I require an answer to. I wish to be able to manipulate the code like this (this is a basic example of my plans, so you are able to understand the two components I wish to be able to pull through):

```
<div class="site-branding">
    <a href="<?php get_custom_logo_url(); ?>" class="box-link">
        <img src="<?php get_custom_logo_src(); ?>" class="site-logo" alt="Logo">
    </a>
</div>
```

I am using a blank theme, with the logo and link already in place in the back-end of Wordpress.

Using this snippet in my header results in the logo and link to display as you would expect:

```
<?php the_custom_logo(); ?>
```

Thank you to all contributors, Jason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `wp_get_attachment_image_src` to get the image properties and URL:

```php
$logo = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $logo , 'full' );
$image_url = $image[0];
$image_width = $image[1];
$image_height = $image[2];
```

**Edit**: *Adding more information based on your comment.*

The URL it points to is simply made with `home_url`:

```php
esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );
```

Another thing often forgotten when using this method is honoring the content of the alt if it's set in the media:

```php
$alt = get_post_meta( $logo, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
if ( empty( $alt ) ) {
    // Use site title if no alt is provided.
    $alt = get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' );
}
```

I'd encourage looking at the source of [get_custom_logo](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_custom_logo/) as it would use most of this.

It's also worth mentioning if you're developing this theme for release on [WordPress.org/themes](https://WordPress.org/themes) - it's a requirement to use `the_custom_logo` or `get_custom_logo` over rolling out your own solution.

For this reason there is a filter for the HTML output in `get_custom_logo`, which might be best to use and replace the bits you need.  The function `get_custom_logo` (used by `the_custom_logo`) also handle a bit more like multisite and ensuring the placeholder is there for the customizer preview.  The usage would be something like this:

```php
add_action( 'get_custom_logo', function( $html ) {
    $new_url = 'href="' . get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo_url', esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) ) .'"';
    $new_link_class = 'class="box-link"';
    $html = str_replace( 'href="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '"', $new_url, $html );
    $html = str_replace( 'class="custom-logo-link"', $new_link_class, $html );
    return $html;
} );
```

That would read a value of the theme_mod `custom_logo_url` which could come from a customizer control, and changes the class from `.custom-logo-link` to `.box-link` in your example.

Comment: Thats a great method to handle the image, is there a way to gather the link associated with the themes logo (not the link to the logo, where it will point)? I require both. Add that to your answer so I can upvote and accept c:

Comment: That is absolutely spot on buddy, appreciate the update and the extension into the alt text. Please upvote my question if you enjoyed answering!